# Count no of values from last till blank cell

Tags: excel-formula

[sample example for my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Xkh.jpg)

**Here I use this following formula ->** =MAX(IF(LEN(C2:AF2)<>0,COLUMN(C2:AF2))) - MAX(IF(LEN(C2:AF2)=0,COLUMN(C2:AF2)))

and -> =COLUMNS(C6:L6)-MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,C6:L6) give you no of blank cells from right side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in AF2 and fill down.

```
=MATCH(1E+99, C2:AF2)-AGGREGATE(14, 7, COLUMN(2:2)/(C2:INDEX(2:2, 1, MATCH(1E+99, C2:AF2))=""), 1)
```

[image]